# Order by an array by key in laravel

Tags: laravel, sql-order-by

I am using the below query to get the matched ID from the following tables where I will get only `student_id`.

With this `student_id`, I have to find the matched row from `students` table, and then I want to `orderBy()` the keys (e.g. name) from `students` table.

I make the relationship between `student_mapping` and `student` model.

```
$mapps = Student_mapping::select('student_id');

if($request->session_id) {
    $mapps = $mapps->where('session', '=', $request->session_id);
}
if($request->class_id) {
    $mapps = $mapps->where('class_id', '=', $request->class_id);

    if($request->group_id) {
        $mapps = $mapps->where('group_id', '=', $request->group_id);

        if($request->section_id) {
            $mapps = $mapps->where('section_id', '=', $request->section_id);
        }
    }
}

$mapps = $mapps->get();

$students = [];

foreach($mapps as $map) {
    if($map->student)
    {
        $students[] = Student::find($map->student_id);
    }
}
```

I have to make $students->orderBy('name', 'ASC'), But I can't do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `User::where('id', $map->student_id)->orderBy('name', 'ASC')`; this doesn't look useful since `id` is unique anyway.

On a separate note, it looks like your code will suffer from multiple calls to the db.

You could simplify your query to be:

```
$student_ids = $mapps->pluck('student_id');
$students = Student::whereIn('id', $student_ids)->orderBy('name', 'ASC')->get();
```

> PS: Eloquent (Model) wraps around QueryBuilder. See [example of ordering or groupby in the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset)

Answer (score 0):

It'd be faster and better to get the query like this:

```
$students = Student::whereIn('id', $mapps)->orderBy('id')->get();
```

This would give you a `Collection` of all students which should be ordered by ID. If you want it as an array, remember calling the `->toArray()` method on the collection, but it should serve its purpose as a collection either way.

Answer (score 0):

```
$students = [];

foreach($mapps as $map) {
    if($map->student)
    {
        $students[] = Student::find($map->student_id);
    }
}
```

by laravel collection class [see](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-sort)

```
return   collect($student)->sortBy('name')->values()->all();
```